# How can I make PhpStorm parse EJS syntax inside a blade template?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

How can I make PhpStorm parse `<%= ... %>` inside the `blade.php` file?

I have installed EJS plugin, and it does a good work if I use `.ejs` 
extension, but doing nothing when in blade file.

I've tried adding `*.blade.php` wildcard under `settings > editor > file types > EJS` but then the blade extension gets reassigned to it and then blade doesn't show right.

Comment: It's not gonna work I'm afraid. You cannot have 2 nested template languages (Blade + EJS) in the same file without special support from a plugin (e.g. like you can have pure PHP blocks in .blade.php files -- PHP itself is a template language and Blade is templating engine on top of it). Right now template languages (Blade/EJS) are not injectable into another language (only "proper" languages are).

Comment: I do not know what kind of code you have got there ... but the best I personally can suggest here is to have these "fragments" in separate files if possible (i.e. all EJS code to be in separate file (where you will have proper EJS syntax support) and then "include" it into blade file). If you need to pass some config/variable -- do it in blade file and EJS will only consume them.

Comment: Note that EJS, or Handlebar or whatever templating you choose has nothing to do with Backbone. There's no _Backbone syntax_ since it's just a JavaScript lib.